# How to get ConnectionString Value from appsetting.json into Repository in Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to Net Core WebAPI, I'm developing Core Web API without EF. I got stuck were i'm not able to get Connection String from appsetting.json into my Repository

I have created Constructor of CommonRepository and used IConfiguration  to get connection string value

```
public CommonRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
```

but while creating object of common repository it is giving an error

```
CommonRepository commonRepository =new CommonRepository();
```

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'CommonRepository.CommonRepository(IConfiguration)'

Comment: Create a model to store the connection string, populate it on startup from configuration and store the model using options pattern. Inject the model where needed and access connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer the following code to create and use the CommonRepository, then, get the connection string.

CommonRepository:

```
public interface ICommonRepository
{
    string GetConnectionstring();
}

public class CommonRepository : ICommonRepository
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public CommonRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public string GetConnectionstring()
    {
        return _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
}
```

Register the above repository in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddScoped<ICommonRepository, CommonRepository>();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ICommonRepository _commonRepositoty;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ICommonRepository commonRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _commonRepositoty = commonRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var str = _commonRepositoty.GetConnectionstring();
        return View();
    }
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, see [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done using dependency injection which should be setup in the startup.cs file. As such:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

ASP.Net will automatically pass in the config to this class from the host. We use this to create a singleton which will inject the config into all constructors that use IConfiguration as a parameter. Explained [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)